# How to loop through XAML code in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have designed a UI in XAML (UWP). Now I want to loop through it, as the same UI will be generated for the certain number of times, the number is coming from SQLite. So basically I want to create it with code behind.
For instance, suppose I have the following XAML:

```
<Grid Background="Black">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="btnBack" Click="btnBack_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Transparent" Height="50" Width="100">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="Assets/arrow_left.png" Height="40" Width="50" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="TWS" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Gill Sans MT" />

    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="btnForward" Click="btnForward_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Transparent" Height="50" Width="100" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="Assets/arrow_right.png" Height="40" Width="50"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

And I have to generate it one after another for 4 times(this will change everytime). As we can't write any C# code in .xaml file so I can not loop it.
I also know that I can write the corresponding C# code in .xaml.cs file and then it can be loop through. Is there any other method to do it? Also, it will be very helpful if anyone can suggest any tool(if present) which can convert XAML to C# code behind.

Comment: Encapsulate your XAML into **UserControl**. Define some `<Canvas x:Name="Spawner"/>` in your **MainPage**. From code create an instance `Spawner.ChildrenAdd(new YourUserControlName());`

Comment: Ok. But I need unique x:Name for every generated element, eg every button with a unique name so that I can clearly do my task depending on which button is clicked.

Comment: To distinguish buttons in **UserControl** instances you may create `public event EventHandler Clicked` in it. On button click event you may invoke this event and pass `this` (your **UserControl** reference) as sender. Your **MainPage** must be subscribed to this event and you will receive the necessary **UserControl** in sender.

Comment: Ok sounds good. I will give it a try.